# Rake task - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, koala

I tinkering my way into creating a rake task that grabs the amount of checkins for a given page throw facebook-graph. I usign the koala gem and rails.

I do this by creating a rake task:

```
task :get_likes => :environment do
    require 'koala'
    # Grab the first user in the database
    user = User.first

    # Loop throw every school & and call count_checkins
    School.columns.each do |column|
        user.facebook.count_checkins(column.name, user)
    end
end
# Count like for every school else return 0
def count_checkins(name, u)
    a = u.facebook.fql_query('SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = "' + name + '"')
    if a[0].nil?
        return 0
    else 
        return b = a[0]["checkins"]
    end
end
# Initialize an connection to the facebook graph
def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

But I get a error:

```
private method `count_checkins' called for #<Koala::Facebook::API:0x007fae5bd348f0>
```

Any ideas or better way to code a rake task would be awesome!

Check the full error here: https://gist.github.com/shuma/4949213

Comment: Where are the last 2 methods defined?

Comment: @mind.blank In the rake file.

Comment: You need to define them in the relevant class definitions instead. e.g. `user.facebook` will try to call the `facebook` method on the User class, but the method you defined isn't attached to that class.

Comment: @SeanD. When I do that I get this error: undefined method count_checkins instead.

Comment: Try doing `def self.count_checkins(name)` and putting it in the User model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really format this properly in a comment, so I'll put it in an answer. I would put the following into the User model:

```
# Count like for every school else return 0
def count_checkins(name)
    a = self.facebook.fql_query('SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE name = "' + name + '"')
    if a[0].nil?
        return 0
    else 
        return b = a[0]["checkins"]
    end
end

# Initialize an connection to the facebook graph
def facebook
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end
```

Then change the rake task to:

```
task :get_likes => :environment do
    require 'koala'
    # Grab the first user in the database
    user = User.first

    # Loop throw every school & and call count_checkins
    School.columns.each do |column|
        user.count_checkins(column.name)
    end
end
```

That way count_checkins is defined on the user model, rather than trying to modify a class within Koala -- and you aren't duplicating work by having to pass around more User and Facebook parameters than are necessary.

Comment: Whether or not that actually makes sense given the contents of `School.columns` I don't know, but it should at least fix the undefined method problem.

Comment: Nice idea, but it still dosent find the method. undefined method `count_checkins'

Comment: Is the new `def count_checkins` block within the User class definition (between `class User` and `end`)? Also, you should probably check to make sure you're actually finding a user record in your rake task; is it possible you're getting nil?

Comment: I find a couple of bugs, and I fix it. I like your code, good job mate!